# Null pointer exception when using extent report

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have two classes `baseClass` and `TesCaseLoginPage`. When i am trying 
to execute `TesCaseLoginPage` class without any Report/Logger 
(ExtentReport),Test case is getting pass. But when i am puttin extend report 
into my code, I am getting `NullPointerException` .Could you please help me

I have written `report.endTest(logger);` in line no 51. Tried to comment 
this line and then executed.
This time i got same error in line no 50 i.e.

`logger.log(LogStatus.INFO,"Browser Closed");`. So every time i am commenting error line, getting same error in new log related line only.

Error log is as below :

```
Url : http://store.demoqa.com//products-page//your-account// FAILED
> CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass close java.lang.NullPointerException at
> testcases.testCaseLoginPage.close(testCaseLoginPage.java:51) at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> 
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.
> java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at 
> org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
> 
> at
> org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:515)
> at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:217)
> at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:144)
> at 
> org.testng.internal.invokeAfterClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:217)
> at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:115)
> at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756) at
> org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610) at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)   at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382) at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340) at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289) at
> org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52) at
> org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86) at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293) at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218) at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133) at
> org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104) at
> org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
> at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236) at
> org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81) FAILED:
> login java.lang.NullPointerException at
> testcases.testCaseLoginPage.login(testCaseLoginPage.java:35) at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
> reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

Here is the code :

**baseClass.java**

```
package testcases;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;
import factory.BrowserFactory;
import factory.DataproviderFactory;
import pages.LoginPage;

public class baseClass 
{

    WebDriver driver;
    ExtentReports report;
    ExtentTest logger;
    String loginText;

    public void setUP()
    {
        driver=BrowserFactory.getBrowser("chrome");
        driver.get(DataproviderFactory.getConfig().getApplicationurl());
    }

    public void loginIntoApplication()
    {       
        LoginPage login=PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
        login.Login(DataproviderFactory.getExcel().getData(0, 0, 0), 
        DataproviderFactory.getExcel().getData(0, 0, 1));
    }

    public String LoginVerification()
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        //WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[@id='wp-admin-bar-my-account']/a")));

        loginText=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='wp-admin-bar-my-account']/a")).getText();
        logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Logiin account text has been captured successfully");
        return loginText;
    }

    public void TearDown()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

**testCaseLoginPage.java**

```
package testcases;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test; 
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;
import pages.LoginPage;


public class testCaseLoginPage extends baseClass
{

    //WebDriver driver;
    //baseClass base=PageFactory.initElements(driver, baseClass.class);

    @BeforeTest
    public void initial()
    {
        base.setUP();
    }

    @Test(priority=1)
    public void login()
    {

        base.loginIntoApplication();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        //WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Howdy')]")));
        logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Logiin into applicaion successfully");
        //LoginPage login=PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);

        LoginPage login=new LoginPage(driver);
        base.LoginVerification();
        System.out.println("Login Text : "+base.loginText);

        Assert.assertEquals(base.loginText, login.Exp,"Unable to verify login verification");   
        logger.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Verified login account with expected user successfully");

    }

    @AfterTest
    public void close()
    {
        base.TearDown();
        logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Browser Closed");
        report.endTest(logger);
        report.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Trying to import your code gives me alot of errors. base.setUP(); This can't be resolved.

Comment: You are not initialized logger and report object which you have created in base class.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize the logger in your Test.

use this line:

```
logger = extent.startTest("Test Name","Description");
```

Make it the first line even before you call the logger in your test.

For reference see [Software Automata - Extent Reports in Selenium](https://softwareautomata.wordpress.com/2017/07/09/extent-reports-in-selenium/)